# puts "string" and another object

Tags: ruby, string, puts

I would like to know if it's possible to use the puts statement in the following way:

```
array = ["a", "new", "array"]
puts "array length is: " + array.length
```

If I use the + operator then I get an error. I'm trying to get this output:

```
array length is 3
```

I know how to do this in Java but what is the Ruby equivalent?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either

```
puts "array length is:  #{array.length}"
```

or

```
puts "array length is: " + array.length.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
puts "array length is: #{array.length}"
```

Comment: Thank you, as I was fiddling with the code I figured it out. This is the right answer and as Arup said, you have won. I will mark it as correct. Thanks for replying to my silly newbie question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to put one variable inside a string in ruby:

```
#{array.length}
```

So it would become

```
puts "array length is: #{array.length}"
```